# HTTP POST Request using Rest Assured (Example)

Tags: java, rest, post, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Below POST Method can be used to run the HTTP POST request in Rest Assured using Java

better to go with GSON dependency

```
{
    RestAssured.baseURI = API_URL;

    RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();

    request.header("Key1", "Value1");
    request.header("Key2", ""+Value2+""); //If value is getting capture from other variable

    JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
    requestParams.put("Payload Key1", "Payload Value1"); 
    requestParams.put("Payload Key2", "Payload Value2");

    request.body(requestParams.toString());
    Response response = request.post(""); //last word of URL
    int StatusCode = response.getStatusCode(); //Get Status Code
    System.out.println("Status code : " + StatusCode);       
    System.out.println("Response body: " + response.body().asString()); //Get Response Body
}
```

Can use this code for POST Request in Rest Assured - Java

Comment: So what is your question then? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing API testing using Rest Assured. You have to specify the contentType to "application/json" and in post method you need to pass the endpoint.